# Travis CI build triggered twice

Tags: git, github, travis-ci

I am using the following config.

```
before_install:
  - "sudo apt-get update"
  - "sudo apt-get install --no-install-recommends texlive-full"
script:
  - pdflatex file.tex
deploy:
  provider: releases
  file:
    - file.pdf
  api_key:
    secure: "MY_API_KEY"
  skip_cleanup: true
```

When I do `git push origin master --tags`, it creates two builds in Travis. One for master branch and the other for the tag.
I want to only build and deploy when a tag is present. So I added the condition in line 1 as follows:

```
if: tag IS present
before_install:
  - "sudo apt-get update"
  - "sudo apt-get install --no-install-recommends texlive-full"
script:
  - pdflatex file.tex
deploy:
  provider: releases
  file:
    - file.pdf
  api_key:
    secure: "MY_API_KEY"
  skip_cleanup: true
```

But now then it builds fine and only when the tag is present but it does not deploy. Gives the following warning:

```
Skipping a deployment with the releases provider because this branch is not permitted
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to add `tags: true` under on in `deploy` section to trigger the deployment on tagging.

Here's an example of `.travis.yml` that triggers the deployment on tagging:

```
deploy:
  provider: ...
  api_key:  ...
  on:
    tags:   true
```

You may also trigger deployment by specifying the branch or branches in `$TRAVIS_BRANCH` (See [documentation](https://docs.travis-ci.com/user/deployment/)).

Comment: According to the [travis docs](https://docs.travis-ci.com/user/deployment/#conditional-releases-with-on) the branch is ignored in this case: `tags: true`: deployment is triggered if and only if `$TRAVIS_TAG` is set. Depending on your workflow, you may set `$TRAVIS_TAG` explicitly, even if this is a non-tag build when it was initiated. This causes the branch condition to be ignored.

Comment: @fragmentedreality: Thank you for your input! I've updated my answer accordingly. Please review if there's any discrepancy. Thanks, again!